# Non-i.i.d Empirical Risk Minimization

Tags: machine-learning

It's a post which already posted on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790021/non-i-i-d-empirical-risk-minimization).
I'm not a statistician so please forgive me if I pose a silly question, but it's a real problem for me in my research. Suppose we have defined risk in a regression problem as $R(f)=\int l(f(x),y)p(x)dx$ in which we want to estimate $f$ based on the data.The function $l$ is loss functions which measures the discrepancy between output of the function $f$ and provided label $y$ for every $x$.

If we sample i.i.d then it's possible that we substitute $p(x)=1/n\sum^ n_{i=1}δ(x−x_i)$. The function $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta function. Result will be Empirical Risk minimization. i.e. $R(f)=1/n\sum^n_{i=1}l(f(x_i),y_i)$. But if our samples are not i.i.d, then it's not possible to write $p(x)$ as above, so ERM in this simple form is not possible.
This is a problem which we face in many machine learning scenarios. The problem is what can we can do in the case of non-i.i.d samples. More specifically, if our samples are not independent, what can be done? how to write $p(x)$ similar to the one above that considers the effect of non-i.i.d samples? If I have any misunderstanding or if I posed the questions wrongly please comment. Also, is there any source or material directly related to this problem in literature.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: Cross-posted on math.SE:  http://math.stackexchange.com/q/790021/14578  Note that cross-posting is normally prohibited by site policy.

Comment: This question was [also posted on Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/790021) and has been answered there.